# drag and drop get ids of multiple image in droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I'm new to jquery, there is no question on this, I wanted my submit button able to get ids of multiple images in droppable, anyone can help? please help me or guide me along... I need to get the ids of the image that is only dragged inside the droppable and when submit button is pressed.. Display the image that is only inside droppable..

**jsFiddle**

```
https://jsfiddle.net/xInfinityMing/azvvhxvL/
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
$("#dragIcons img").draggable({
  revert: "invalid",
  refreshPositions: true,
  cursor: "move",
  cursorAt: {
    top: 56,
    left: 56
  },
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    ui.helper.removeClass("end-draggable");
    ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    ui.helper.addClass("end-draggable");
    ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
  }
});

$("#briefcase-full").droppable({
  greedy: true,
  tolerance: 'touch',
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var id = ui.draggable.attr("id");
    alert(id);
    if ($("#briefcase").length == 0) {
      $("#briefcase-droppable").html("");
    }

      ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
      $("#briefcase-droppable").append(ui.draggable);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, all the dragged element will go inside the `droppable`. so you can use `children` to check every elements.

`$("#briefcase-droppable").children(".icons").each(function() {
     var icon_id= $(this).attr("id");
});`

JSFiddle : [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ztLvvddq/2/)

I suggest you to use class instead of using `img` element to attach `draggable` event.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. but I want display it out.. how do I display it out?

Comment: @YiMing you mean like the id shown on the list? 
Like this one : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ztLvvddq/3/)

Comment: Thanks for your help but I mean how do I know how many draggable image is inside droppable! like when there is two image been drop inside when submitted it alert me there is two image.. not display the two image id.. sorry for misunderstanding..

Comment: okay, then you just need to use `length` to know how many icon is dragged.

`$("#briefcase-droppable").children(".icons").length`